# Caching hundreds of files on iOS app for 24-48 hours: all in Document folder or better in multiple folders?

Tags: ios, iphone

If you need to cache hundreds of files on disk for an iOS app, is it prudent to store them all in the app's Document folder? (They will be cached then deleted after 24-48 hours.) Are there any drawbacks, e.g., searching for a given file is slower if the folder has too many files? Or should you store them in separate folders for performance reasons? What is considered best practice for iOS?

Comment: Try it. See which approach works better for you.

Comment: @rmaddy that's the plan, just want to be proactive and find out if there are other issues beyond performance to be mindful of, or if there is a standard design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to store them in the Documents folder as these can be accessed via iTunes file sharing. You usually store them in a cache directory. You can access cache URL's by using

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].firstObject
```

Depending on if these files shouldn't be deleted by iOS if the system is running out of storage space you might want to use the Library directory instead of caches by passing `NSLibraryDirectory` into the method above instead of `NSCachesDirectory`

see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html for a more detailed explanation of the different storage types on iOS

Comment: Thanks, but is it prudent to store them all in the same folder, or does performance improve if you use multiple folders?

Comment: Hundreds of files is not that many, my guess is performance would not be affected by having them all in the same folder. Try it out and see if it's an issue. If so (or if you want to organize them differently) then write the extra code to do that, but i would start with just caching them and seeing how it goes :)

Comment: Performance is probably going to be something you will have to test out. I would be surprised though, if there is any noticeable drop in access times unless you start storing thousands of files. I would suggest you write a quick test app and try out the scenarios you have in mind. But unless you hit a sizeable issue, I'd go with whatever is the simplest to work with. Adding directories will add complexity to your code.

Comment: @drekka agreed just wanted to see if there were other unexpected drawbacks on iOS and also if generally hundreds or thousands is the upper bound on storing files in a directory. thanks.